# Enter user registration information in the database

Tags: database, user-registration

can you tell me what's wrong with this code?

I simply have to enter those data in the user database on Wordpress.

Here is my code:

```
// Inserisce utente nel DB
$user_data = [
    'user_login' => $nickname,
    'user_pass'  => wp_generate_password(),
    'user_email' => $email,
];
$user_id = wp_insert_user($user_data);


// Inserisce i meta dati di un utente nel DB
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $nome);
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $cognome);
$u = new WP_User( $user_id );
$u->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
$u->add_role( 'bronze_member_ga' );
```

The only thing I added in the wpdd_users database structure is that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

[image]

**UPDATE:**

The problem is not in the user's cache. Those work perfectly.

The problem is the username checks that I had not made.

I write to him and then post them.

Comment: Can you clarify what's going wrong? Is the user inserted but not the meta?

Comment: I checked and I see this:
The $ userdata array is created correctly and if I print it with a print_r ($ userdata) all the entered data is shown.

But when I go to add them via $ user_id = wp_insert_user ($ user_data); these are not entered.

Consequently, of course, even usermetas are not inserted.

Comment: So a user is crated but the user meta is not? Or is no user created at all? It's unclear what's wrong, I also see you don't check for errors in your code, `$user_id` might be a `WP_Error` object

Comment: Neither was created.

Comment: Maybe it can be a value that I changed in the database? It seems to me that it no longer records the data from that change if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @MatteoFeduzi you shouldn't modify WP core tables, your changes will be undone on the next WP database update

Comment: Can you tell me how you have that value that at least reimposed it as it was before?

Comment: You need a value for each entry in wp_users. Nulls are not allowed, which is what your code is passing.

Comment: I tried to insert the values ​also in this way but nothing. $user_data = array( 'user_login' => $nickname, 'user_pass' => wp_generate_password(), 'user_email' => $email ); No, I don't insert the datatime value into the array because it should insert it automatically. This is the updated user database photo: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zexNp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zexNp.png)

Comment: I not sure what you mean by your comment about reimposing, but when WP updates its database schema, it enforces the new schema, adding and removing columns as needed so that it matches what it's supposed to be. That includes removing new columns that you add, and restoring columns you modified or removed. This is done via `dbdelta`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to note:

- there is no error checking on `wp_insert_user`, so there's no way to know if it failed and why
- `wp_insert_user` can be used to set the role etc, the follow up calls aren't needed, [if you read the official docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user#Notes), there are parameters for those fields
- Never modify the WP Core database tables yourself, if you need extra columns, store the data in user meta, any changes you make get undone and overwritten when WP updates its database table schema, all that extra data would be lost

So, lets do it this way:

```php
$user_data = [
    'user_login' => $nickname,
    'user_pass'  => wp_generate_password(),
    'user_email' => $email,
    'first_name' => $nome,
    'last_name' => $cognome,
    'role' => 'bronze_member_ga'
];
$user_id = wp_insert_user($user_data);
```

Then confirm that it actually created the user, and if not, why it failed:

```php
//On failure
if( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    wp_die( "Failed to create user: " . $user_id->get_error_message() );
}
```

**Update:** Based on your responses it would appear that several assumptions you've made are untrue, specifically that `$nickname` has a value and is valid

So lets add a validation and sanitisation step before filling `$user_data`:

```php
if ( empty( $nickname ) ) {
    wp_die( 'Failure: $nickname is empty and must have a value' );
}
if ( !is_email( $email ) ) {
    wp_die( 'Failure: $email is not an email' );
}
if ( empty( $nome ) ) {
    wp_die( 'Failure: $nome is empty and must have a value' );
}
if ( empty( $cognome ) ) {
    wp_die( 'Failure: $cognome is empty and must have a value' );
}
```

For your database changes, you should instead make use of `update_user_meta` and `get_user_meta` to store the additional values. Using extra columns in the user table will cause problems, and data loss on WordPress updates

Comment: I have placed the database to the previous version but nothing has been solved.

I followed your instructions and I see this error.

Ideas of what it means?

Failed to create user: Unable to create a user without a login name.

Comment: While the user_login is passed correctly.

Comment: @MatteoFeduzi are you absolutely sure that the value is valid? What are you using to test? And are you absolutely sure it is in the `$user_data` array? How are you checking that? Where does `$nickname` come from?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't solved it yet, I thought it was that but it's not ...

Comment: I think the problem is due to the caches.

In fact at the bottom of the usage file:

wp_set_current_user ($ user_id);
wp_set_auth_cookie ($ user_id);
wp_redirect (home_url (). '/ dashboard');
exit;

Comment: I confirm that it works correctly from my mobile.

I actually did a lot of testing and it could be that.

Could this also happen to the user? If yes, how can I prevent it?

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated issue to what your question describes, the type of device has no influence on how `wp_insert_user` works, you need to do further debugging, and verify that things have the values you think they do directly, rather than from the observed behaviour, either via a debugger, or by displaying them directly via `var_export` etc

Comment: I solved the problem by myself, thanks anyway.

Comment: @MatteoFeduzi can you post the answer with the solution?